# Fix the exception System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '='.'

Tags: c#, sql

When I run the ide show the following exception

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '='.'

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM lwpos_categories  WHERE parent_id=" + ddlCategory.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Don't concatenate the string value, use a parameter instead.

Comment: I think you would need a ";" after adding your value.

Comment: What data type is parent_id. What is the value of ddlCategory.SelectedValue?

Comment: this shows you the parameter method:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `ddlCategory.SelectedValue` is empty. The following can fix this exception (and I recommend using `SqlParameters`).

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM lwpos_categories  WHERE parent_id= '" + ddlCategory.SelectedValue + "'";
```

Comment: I think it would have been better to give a really, really strong warning about why this code is dangerous rather than just mentioning `SqlParameter` in parentheses, as if it's something that's not really important.